# Data visualization / business dashboard software

Tags: data-visualization, reporting, business-intelligence, dashboard

We are an IT company looking for a web application for dashboards.
Typical use case: a dashboard with 14-day charts of KPI metrics.

Has to meet the following requirenents: 
1. Web application, accessible from any browser, no client/plugin installation required.
2. Hosted on premises so that the data does not leave company datacenter. 
3. Support of pulling data from an SQL source. 
4. As easy to set up and fill with metrics as possible.

I was offered to use Looker, but we don't need full BI/analytics functionality, so looking for cheaper alternatives meeting our business requirements.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Metabase.

1. It can be install in 5 minutes on any Windows, Linux server or Docker.
2. It's installed on premises so no data goes outside of your network.
3. It allows connections to multiple Databases. (Postgres, MySQL, Druid, SQL Server, Redshift, MongoDB, Google BigQuery, SQLite, H2, Crate, MariaDB)
4. It's Open Source so no license needed
5. It get's updated almost every month adding features and solving bugs
6. It connects to slack and send pulses to members of your teams

http://www.metabase.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Dashboard Platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) can meet your requirements.

1. Web application, accessible from any browser, no client/plugin installation required: Yes
2. Hosted on premises so that the data does not leave company datacenter.: Yes.
3. Support of pulling data from an SQL source. : Yes
4. As easy to set up and fill with metrics as possible.: Yes

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard]

The dashboard platform and more are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The licensing cost is not expensive even otherwise. Note: I work for Syncfusion.